# Mostrar datos en input datetime-local desde la DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy usando fullcalendar, y al hacer click en un evento estoy pasando sus datos a los campos de un modal, todos los demás datos se muestran en los inputs correspondientes, excepto a los dos inputs de tipo  datetime-local que no se muestran, sin embargo si paso los datos a otro input se muestra correctamente(25/09/2017 17:20). Creo que puede ser el formato, alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Se muestra el formato en que se esta pasando el dato al input
[image: Se muestra como se esta pasando el dato al input]

Formato en mi Base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Javascript

```
 eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {


      $('#event_id').val(event.id);
      $('#id_mot2').val(event.mot);
      $('#nombre_estudiante').val(event.estudiante);
      $('#jc2').val(event.jefe_c);
      $('#rut_estudiante').val(event.rut_estudiante)


       //Estos son los dos campos datetime-local

       $('#start_f').val(moment(event.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));

        $('#end_f').val(moment(event.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));


        $('#modal_editar').modal();


},
```

Comment: Agrega los datos que vienen de la base de datos de ese registro que estamos viendo. Saludos :D

Comment: En realidad no es relevante, por eso no lo puse, seria solamente los campos datatime  de donde puse la imagen

Comment: Los datos se traen correctamente si los muestro en otro input de tipo text, el problema es al tratar de mostrarlos a un input de tipo datetime-local